# How do I make aggregate query return empty set instead of NULL row?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT t1.name, MAX(t2.value)
FROM t2
JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
WHERE t2.t1_id = 1 AND t2.text_id = 16;
```

However, when t2 selection is empty, it returns a row containing NULL values (because of MAX function returning NULL when called on an empty set). I would like it to return an empty set instead. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What about `ISNULL(MAX(...), 0)`

Comment: @Mivaweb, it will return result set with value zero. He wants empty set.

Comment: I'm not able to test this at the moment, but can you not just add `AND t2.value IS NOT NULL` to your where clause?

Comment: @KevinNagurski, it still returns a row of NULLs. Also, I would like to know a more general solution where the only condition to rely on is MAX(...) not being null.

Comment: Try adding it to your `JOIN` condition so that it doesn't match.

Comment: @KevinNagurski, I am getting the same result when using it in JOIN condition.

Comment: Damn, well, I'm outa ideas :-)

Comment: Your query does not make sense.  It has an aggregation function but no `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in sql server ...

```
with cte as
(
SELECT t1.name, MAX(t2.value) a
FROM t2
JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
WHERE t2.t1_id = 1 AND t2.text_id = 16;
)
select * from cte where a is not null
```

try this in Mysql

```
  select p.* from 
(
    SELECT t1.name, MAX(t2.value) a
    FROM t2
    JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
    WHERE t2.t1_id = 1 AND t2.text_id = 16;
) p where p.a is not null
```

Answer (score 3):

Having clause fits perfectly here:

```
SELECT
  t1.name, MAX(t2.value)
FROM
  t2 JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
WHERE
  t2.t1_id = 1 AND t2.text_id = 16
-- GROUP BY something?
HAVING
  MAX(t2.value) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `RETURN` when you don't want to get a resultset.

```
IF ((SELECT MAX(t2.Value) FROM t2) > 0)
  SELECT t1.name, MAX(t2.value)
  FROM t2
  JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
  WHERE t2.t1_id = 1 AND t2.text_id = 16
ELSE
  RETURN
```

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506935/how-do-i-make-aggregate-query-return-empty-set-instead-of-null-row#comment49092313_30506935) by [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff).

To wrap select query in another select query is good idea but when we have many aggregate fields then it will become cumbersome to do and think about that you have to make change like this to more than 10 queries.

You should use **GROUP BY** clause to query which will help you to fix your mentioned issue but more than that it will help you to get aggregate values(field wise) based on group by clause. In your case you should use GROUP BY t1.name can work.
So your aggregate result set will be group by name.

If you do not use GROUP BY then think that you have name field which have 100 unique values but you'll only 1 row which all rows aggregated data which may be wrong implementation.

[Here's](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx) some more details about aggregate functions and group by.